# Does a "semi-dependent" sequential event affect probability?

Tags: probability

Say I have a set of 5 different cards and pick one at random, let's say the ace of hearts.

$1/5 = 20\%$

Then, I put the ace into a different set of only 4 cards (including the ace) and pick again. This time, I *also* pick the ace.

$1/4 = 25\%$

$1/7 * 1/4 = 5\%$

Does "surviving" the first round affect the probability of picking the ace again or is it still treated as independent events?

Comment: Not too sure if your question is completely clear.

Comment: This is not clear.  Obviously the probability is higher then it would be if the new set didn't contain the ace (or if we did not know if it contained the ace or not).   What did you mean?

Comment: Can you edit your question for clarity?

Comment: Poorly worded the question before. I edited the question to try and be more clear.

Comment: Still not clear.  The fact that the Ace survived the first round (and was then transferred to the second group) tells us that it is in fact in the second group!  Hence it is much more likely to be chosen than, say, the King of Spades (which, after all, is almost certainly not in the second group).